# Xcode13: "Cannot convert value of type 'CVPixelBuffer' to expected argument type"

Tags: coreml, image-classification, xcode13, cvpixelbuffer

I'm a very novice coder, and I'm working on my first CoreML project, where I use an Image Classification model. I used some tutorials online, and I converted the uploaded image to a CV pixel buffer.
This is my code:

```
let model = classifier()
        private func performImageClassification(){
        let currentImage = uploadedImage //image that was uploaded
        let resizedImage = currentImage.resizeTo(size: CGSize(width: 255, height:255))
        guard let pixelBuffer = resizedImage?.toBuffer() else { return }
        let output = try? model.prediction(input: pixelBuffer)
        if let output = output {
        self.classificationLabel = output.classLabel
                }
 }
```

On the line `let output = try? model.prediction(input: pixelBuffer)`, I get the following error: "Cannot convert value of type 'CVPixelBuffer' (aka 'CVBuffer') to expected argument type."

Please help!